# Synchronize SQL CE with a SQL Server using the Sync Framework 2.1 DbSyncException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, synchronization

I try to make a application to that supports offline use. I thought Microsoft Sync frame work would be a good idea.

but I try to make a small demo with only one table in my SQL server database and my SQL CE database:

```
CREATE TABLE [Products] (
  [ID] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
, [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
, [ListPrice] money NOT NULL
);
GO

ALTER TABLE [Products] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);
GO
```

after creating these tables on the server and on my CE I want to try to synchronize. here is the code i made to synchronize these 2 databases:

```
    public void Synchronize()
    {
        using (var serverConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionStringServer))
        using (var clientConnection = new SqlCeConnection(_connectionStringClient))
        {

            var provider1 = new SqlSyncProvider("scopeTest", serverConnection);
            var provider2 = new SqlCeSyncProvider("scopeTest", clientConnection);


            //config

            PrepareServerForProvisioning(provider1,"Products", "ProductTable");
            PrepareClientForProvisioning(provider2, serverConnection, "Products");

            //sync
            SyncOrchestrator sync = new SyncOrchestrator();
            sync.LocalProvider = provider1;
            sync.RemoteProvider = provider2;
            sync.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;
            sync.Synchronize();

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
    private static void PrepareServerForProvisioning(SqlSyncProvider provider, string description, string table)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)provider.Connection;
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning config = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(connection);
        if (!config.ScopeExists(provider.ScopeName))
        {
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(provider.ScopeName);
            scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(description, connection));
            DbSyncTableDescription serverTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(description, connection);
            serverTableDesc.GlobalName = table;
            config.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            config.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);
            config.Apply();

        }


    }


    private void PrepareClientForProvisioning(SqlCeSyncProvider provider, SqlConnection serverConnection, string tablename)
    {
        // create a connection to the SyncCompactDB database
        SqlCeConnection clientConn = (SqlCeConnection)provider.Connection;

        // get the description of ProductsScope from the SyncDB server database
        DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("scopeTest", serverConnection);

        // create CE provisioning object based on the ProductsScope
        SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc);

        if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(provider.ScopeName))
        {            
            // starts the provisioning process
            clientProvision.Apply();
        }
    }
```

the connection strings are working perfectly and also provising on the serverside works wel, after running the method "PrepareServerForProvisioning" de server database created the tables: Products_tracking, Schema_info, Scope_config, and scope_info.

when the code reaches the line: sync.Synchronize(); it throws an error:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncException' occurred in Microsoft.Synchronization.dll

Additional information: An error occurred when initializing adapters for scope 'scopeTest'. Ensure that the scope name specified on the provider exists in the scope metadata table, and that the correct base tables are specified for that scope.  Check the inner exception for any store-specific errors.
```

the innerexception looks like this:
{"Cannot add the SyncAdapter to the SyncAdapterCollection. A SyncAdapter for table 'Products' already exists."}

What am I doing wrong?